# Polars scan s3 multi-part parquet files

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a multipart partitioned parquet on s3. Each partition contains multiple parquet files. The below code narrows in on a single partition which may contain somewhere around 30 parquet files. When I use `scan_parquet` on a s3 address that includes `*.parquet` wildcard, it only looks at the first file in the partition. I verified this with the count of customers. It has the count from just the first file in the partition. Is there a way that it can scan across files?

```
import polars as pl

s3_loc = "s3://some_bucket/some_parquet/some_partion=123/*.parquet"
df = pl.scan_parquet(s3_loc)
cus_count = df.select(pl.count('customers')).collect()
```

If I leave off the `*.parquet` from the s3 address then I get the following error.

`exceptions.ArrowErrorException: ExternalFormat("File out of specification: A parquet file must containt a header and footer with at least 12 bytes")`

Comment: What happens if you exclude the `/*.parquet` from `s3_loc` so that it just sees the directory?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I just updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like from the [user guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/multiple_files/intro.html) on multiple files that to do so requires a loop creating many lazy dfs that you then combine together.

Another approach is to use the `scan_ds` function which takes a pyarrow dataset object.

```
import polars as pl
import s3fs
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
# you can also make a file system with anything fsspec supports
# S3FileSystem is just a wrapper for fsspec
s3_loc = "s3://some_bucket/some_parquet/some_partion=123"
myds = ds.dataset(s3_loc, filesystem=fs)
lazy_df = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(myds)
cus_count = lazy_df.select(pl.count('customers')).collect()
```

Comment: I set up S3FileSystem and it seems like things work till I run a `collect` and then I get an error `exceptions.ComputeError: PyErr { type: <class 'AttributeError'>, value: AttributeError("'_ParquetDatasetV2' object has no attribute 'to_table'"), traceback: Some(<traceback object at 0x7fa4498ff4c0>)`

Comment: See my edit, I'm not sure why it isn't working for you but I put in some code that actually works rather than abstracting anything away.

Comment: Thanks, got it working broadly like above but replaced the ffspec code with fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

Answer (score 1):

The current `0.20.7` version of `polars` simply works

- eagerly with `pl.read_parquet(source)` or
- lazily with `pl.scan_parquet(source)`

Where `source = "s3://bucket/*.parquet"` [source](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/io/cloud-storage/#reading-from-cloud-storage)

---

If the AWS credentials are not available as environment variable, it is possible to pass a `storage_options` argument like:

```
storage_options = {
    "aws_access_key_id": "<secret>",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "<secret>",
    "aws_region": "us-east-1",
}
df = pl.scan_parquet(source, storage_options=storage_options)
```

---

Furthermore if the parquet files are saved with Hive partitions as S3 directories, it is now possible to leaverage PyArrow for it:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(
    ds.dataset("s3://my-partitioned-folder/", format="parquet")
)
```

Comment: Do you know if the method shown for partitioned data is the only method that works?  In my experience, the other method doesn't work for partitioned data, but the dataset version is very slow relative to other methods.  The reason I am looking into polars is speed in an application that spends more time interacting with s3 than anything else.  So, if interacting with s3 is very slow, that won't work.