# How to read partitioned parquet file into polars?

Tags: python, parquet, python-polars

I'd like to read a partitioned parquet file into a polars dataframe.

In spark, it is simple:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("/my/path")
```

The polars documentation says that it should work the same way:

```
df = pl.read_parquet("/my/path")
```

But it gives me the error:

```
raise IsADirectoryError(f"Expected a file path; {path!r} is a directory")
```

How to read this file?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a file path instead of a directory path?

Comment: I think the answer is no - partitions won't work the same as Spark. You'll need to provide one parquet file only. Otherwise, scan_parquet function accepts glob pattern

Answer (score 4):

Here's a snippet of the source code:

```py
if isinstance(source, str) and "*" in source and _is_local_file(source):
    from polars import scan_parquet

    scan = scan_parquet(
            source,
            n_rows=n_rows,
            rechunk=True,
            parallel=parallel,
            row_count_name=row_count_name,
            row_count_offset=row_count_offset,
            low_memory=low_memory,
        )
```

The important bit is that it's looking for an `*` in the source path.

So it seems you just need to do

```py
df = pl.read_parquet("/my/path/*")
```

This only works on local filesystems so if you're reading from cloud storage then you'd have to use `pyarrow` datasets to read multiple files at once without iterating over them yourself.

Comment: It is on cloud, so it is on polars developers, to add this functionality... :(

Comment: I don't think it's *on* the developers to do anything. The functionality exists *through* pyarrow dataset.  Check out https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#reading-from-cloud-storage and then https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_pyarrow_dataset.html

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280212/polars-scan-s3-multi-part-parquet-files/74280532#74280532

Answer (score 4):

As an example using S3 (since you say your files are cloud-hosted), you first establish a filesystem connection (via fsspec) and a dataset against it (as suggested by Dean) and then read into polars from that:

```
from pyarrow.dataset import dataset
from s3fs import S3FileSystem
import polars as pl

# setup cloud filesystem access
cloudfs = S3FileSystem( ... )

# reference multiple parquet files
pyarrow_dataset = dataset(
    source = "s3://bucket/path/*.parquet",
    filesystem = cloudfs,
    format = 'parquet',
)

# load efficiently into polars
ldf = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset( pyarrow_dataset )
```

Comment: does not respect _metadata

Answer (score 4):

Note that the polars native `scan_parquet` now *directly* supports reading hive partitioned data from cloud providers, and it will use the available statistics/metadata to optimise which files/columns have to be read. Should no longer need to defer to `scan_pyarrow_dataset` for this use-case.

[Link to the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html) (see the new "hive_partitioning" param, enabled by default, and the AWS example).

Comment: How do I read / update the statistics/metadata?

Answer (score 0):

```
import polars as pl
from pyarrow import fs
from pyarrow.dataset import dataset


s3 = fs.S3FileSystem(
    access_key=..., 
    secret_key=..., 
    endpoint_override=...,
    )

ds = dataset(config.remote_path, filesystem=s3)
df = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(ds).select(["col1"]).unique().collect(streaming=True)
```

Comment: As of now, pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset does not support streaming. :(

Comment: this is does not respect the _metadata