# How to scan partitioned parquet file from gcs into polars?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-polars

I am trying to scan a folder of multiple parquet file into a polars dataframe. On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093153/how-to-read-partitioned-parquet-file-into-polars) the following is given as an answer using s3.

```
from pyarrow.dataset import dataset
import gcsfs
import polars as pl

# setup cloud filesystem access
cloudfs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="my-project")

# reference multiple parquet files
pyarrow_dataset = dataset(
    source = "gs://bucket/path/*.parquet",
    filesystem = cloudfs,
    format = 'parquet',
)

# load efficiently into polars
ldf = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset( pyarrow_dataset )
```

When trying to change this to use gcs filesystem I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'GCSFileSystem' object has no attribute 'schema'`

Is it possible to read multiple parquet files directly into a polars dataframe?

Comment: On what command do you get that error? Can you do, for example, `cloudfs.ls("")`