# Python Polars: Low memory read, process, writing of parquet to/from Hadoop

Tags: stream, parquet, python-polars, pyarrow, sink

I would like to be able to process very large files in Polars without running out of memory. In the documentation they suggest using scanning, lazyframes and sinks, but it is hard to find proper documentation of how to do this in practice. Hopefully some experts on here can help.

Here I provide an example of what works for "smaller" files that can be handled in memory.

#### 1. Setup

```python
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyarrow._hdfs import HadoopFileSystem

# Setting up HDFS file system
hdfs_filesystem = HDFSConnection('default')
hdfs_out_path_1 = "scanexample.parquet"
hdfs_out_path_2 = "scanexample2.parquet"
```

#### 2. Creating data

```python
# Dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.arange(10000),
    'B': np.arange(10000),
    'C': np.arange(10000),
    'D': np.arange(10000),
})

# Writing to Hadoop
pq_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(hdfs_out_path_1, 
                             schema=pq_table.schema, 
                             filesystem=hdfs_filesystem)

# Appending to parquet file
pq_writer.write_table(pq_table)
pq_writer.close()
```

#### 3. Reading parquet into polars dataframe (in memory)

```python
# Read file
pq_df = pl.read_parquet(source=hdfs_out_path_1, 
                        use_pyarrow=True, 
                        pyarrow_options={"filesystem": hdfs_filesystem})
```

#### 4. Making transforms and writing to file

```python
 # Transforms and write
 pq_df.filter(pl.col('A')>9000)\
      .write_parquet(file = hdfs_out_path_2, use_pyarrow=True, pyarrow_options={"filesystem": hdfs_filesystem})
```

#### 5. Now doing the same with low memory

```python
# Scanning file: Attempt 1
scan_df = pl.scan_parquet(source = hdfs_out_path_2)
ERROR: Cannot find file

# Scanning file: Attempt 2
scan_df = pl.scan_parquet(source = hdfs_filesystem.open_input_stream(hdfs_out_path_1))
ERROR: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not pyarrow.lib.NativeFile
```

According to the [polars documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html) the scan_parquet does not take pyarrow arguments. But it talks about taking some "storage options", which I guess is what I need to use. But how?

#### 6. Example without Hadoop

```python
# Writing to parquet
df.to_parquet(path="testlocal.parquet")

# Read lazily 
lazy_df = pl.scan_parquet(source="testlocal.parquet")

# Transforms and write
lazy_df.filter(pl.col('A')>9000).sink_parquet(path= "testlocal.out.parquet")
```

## UPDATE!

While the accepted answer lets you load your data into a LazyFrame that lazyframe comes with limited functionality, as it cannot sink that data to a file without first collecting it all to the memory!

```python
# Reading into LazyFrame
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
pq_lf = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(
          ds.dataset(hdfs_out_path_1, 
                     filesystem= hdfs_filesystem))

# Attempt at sinking to parquet
pq_lf.filter(pl.col('A')>9000).sink_parquet(path= "testlocal.out.parquet")
PanicException: sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'
```

Comment: Does `hdfs_filesystem.storage_options` return anything? If so you feed that to the storage_options parameter of `scan_parquet`

Comment: It does not have a "storage_options" variable. Do you have a link to some documentation that refers to this "storage_options"?

Comment: have you tried using `pl.scan_parquet(source= hdfs_out_path_1, ...)`

Comment: Yes, I have done it using keyword arguments also.

Answer (score 3):

**Bad news first**, there's not a way to sink to a filesystem directly. You'd have to sink to local storage and then copy if you want to use `sink_parquet`. It looks like that will change soon with [this PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11037) but that isn't in the current release.

**For scanning (ie read-only) you have two options**.

**First option:**
Use [`scan_pyarrow_dataset`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_pyarrow_dataset.html)

That might look like this

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
pq_lf = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(
          ds.dataset(hdfs_out_path_1, 
                        filesystem= hdfs_filesystem
          )
        )
```

and now you have a lazy frame. That's probably the best way as you're already using the pyarrow.fs which seems to be independent of fsspec which is how polars accesses cloud files.

**Second Option:**
use [`scan_parquet`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html)'s storage_options uses `fsspec.open` under the hood. That usage might look like this

```
pq_lf=pl.scan_parquet(f"hdfs://{hdfs_out_path_1}, storage_options=some_dict)
```

What your `storage_options` look like relative to what you do currently in `hdfs_filesystem = HDFSConnection('default')` is going to be determined by your HDFS provider and/or how fsspec interacts with HDFS systems so if it doesn't *just work* you'd have to figure that out separately.

**Quasi sinking workaround**

You can do something like this

```
schema=lazy_df.fetch(1).to_arrow().schema
with pq.ParquetWriter(hdfs_out_path_1, 
                             schema=schema, 
                             filesystem=hdfs_filesystem) as pq_writer:
    for A_chunk in [(9000, 12000), (12000, 15000), (15000,20000)]:
        pq_writer.write_table(
            lazy_df
                .filter(pl.col('A').is_between(A_chunk))
                 # I'd also put a sort here
                .collect()
                .to_arrow()
                )
```

**Pyarrow "sinking" (no polars)**

polars is primarily focused on being an in-memory dataframe library. It has some support for doing some things out of memory but it can't do everything. Apparently, sink_parquet is not yet capable of streaming results from upstream filesystems. pyarrow has more streaming support even with remote non-local filesystems. For instance you can do this...

```
pa_scanner = ds.dataset(hdfs_out_path_1, filesystem= hdfs_filesystem) \
        .scanner(filter=ds.field('A')>9000)
ds.write_dataset(pa_scanner, "path_to_directory_not_a_file", format="parquet")
```

The path needs to be a directory and then it will create files in the directory named as "part-{x}.parquet". Whether or not it'll create a single file or multiple is dependent on your data. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665989/pyarrow-write-dataset-limit-per-partition-files) for more info and tweaks.
The good news about the above is that you can pass `filesystem=hdfs_filesystem` to `ds.write_dataset` and avoid touching the local filesystem. Of course then you're limited to the operations that pyarrow can perform so you've just got to pick your poison.

**Side notes:**

1. Statistics: When polars writes parquet files, even through pyarrow, it does so with statistics off which will preclude future read optimizations with row groups so you need to explicitly specify `statistics=True` if you want statistics.
2. Compression: pyarrow uses snappy compression by default but polars uses zstd. I think, at this point, pyarrow's default is just one of those things that has been the default for so long that they can't change it. I say that because zstd seems to be supported by everything I've tried to use and produces smaller files than snappy without really sacrificing performance so if you're using a pyarrow writer then I'd set `compression='zstd'`.
3. Row Groups: When you use the ParquetWriter like above, then each call to `write_table` will produce a distinct row_group in the resulting file so you can really optimize future reads by having a chunking strategy here that aligns with how you'll read the files later (so long as you turn on statistics).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response, I will be spending time today testing some of your suggestions. I notised that you said it was not possible to scan from remote storage, but isn't that what they do in this answer with S3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280212/polars-scan-s3-multi-part-parquet-files

Comment: I said you can't sink to remote storage.

Comment: True, sorry about that. Reading the parquet file as a dataset, does that not have any memory consequences anywhere in the stack? The line: ds.dataset(hdfs_out_path_1, 
                        filesystem= hdfs_filesystem
          )

Comment: "does that not have any memory consequences anywhere in the stack" It's certainly going to take more than 0 memory but it doesn't load the whole file into memory either. I'm not sure if that answers your question. Have a look at the [docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html). `scan_pyarrow_dataset` turns a pyarrow dataset into a polars lazyframe.

Comment: I was just testing, and though I can now read the data into a lazyframe, it cannot be sinked into a parquet file without "collect()". With this setup I get the message: "sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'". Then we are back a square one.

Comment: Are you trying to sink an LF that you just made or is it one you're doing operations to in between creating it and sinking it?

Comment: I updated my question with a note illustrating what I did. I just read the parquet from hadoop as a dataset, did the same transforms, and then did sink_parquet. It says it is only supported for "normal filesystems".

Comment: I never use sink_parquet so I didn't realize it couldn't operate on remote filesystem sources. You can either use the "Quasi sinking workaround", or the "Pyarrow "sinking" (no polars)" approaches.

Comment: A response to this quote "as it cannot sink that data to a file without first collecting it all to the memory!" When you collect, it only loads the response (plus processing overhead) to your queries in memory, it doesn't load the entire data source to memory. In other words, `lf.collect().filter(...)` is very different in memory consumption than `lf.filter(...).collect()` which is what my first sink work around takes advantage of.

Comment: I am aware of the sink does, but I still run into the same issue as I am just adding a few columns and making a bit of filtering. The output is still too large to fit in memory. That leads us back to the original question. It seems the closest answer so far is that I should not use Hadoop together with Polars, as the sink-functionality is not implemented for Hadoop.

Comment: Yeah the sinking is going to be better than my highly unoptimized workaround so if you're able to use local file system that will be better.