# Error using sink_parquet in Polars library

Tags: python, parquet, python-polars

I’m trying to extract some features from a dataset and then write the results to a Parquet file using the Polars library in Python. Here’s the code I’m using:

```
import ipaddress

import numpy as np
import polars as pl


def extract_session_features(sessions: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.LazyFrame:
    return (
        sessions.with_columns(
            [
                (pl.col("dpkts") + pl.col("spkts")).alias("total_packets"),
                (pl.col("dbytes") + pl.col("sbytes")).alias("total_bytes"),
                (pl.col("dpkts") / pl.col("spkts")).alias("bytes_ratio"),
                (pl.col("dbytes") / pl.col("sbytes")).alias("packets_ratio"),
                (pl.col("spkts") / pl.col("dur")).alias("sent_packets_rate"),
                (pl.col("dpkts") / pl.col("dur")).alias("received_packets_rate"),
                (pl.col("sbytes") / pl.col("dur")).alias("sent_bytes_rate"),
                (pl.col("dbytes") / pl.col("dur")).alias("received_bytes_rate"),
                (pl.col("sbytes") / pl.col("spkts")).alias("mean_pkt_sent_size"),
                (pl.col("dbytes") / pl.col("dpkts")).alias("mean_pkt_recv_size"),
                (
                    pl.col("Timestamp")
                    .diff()
                    .dt.seconds()
                    .fill_null(0)
                    .over("ID")
                    .alias("time_since_last_session")
                ),
            ]
        )
        .with_columns(
            [
                (
                    pl.when(pl.col("^.*(_ratio|_rate).*$").is_infinite())
                    .then(-1)
                    .otherwise(pl.col("^.*(_ratio|_rate).*$"))
                    .keep_name()
                ),
            ]
        )
        .fill_nan(-1)
    )


filtered_sessions = pl.scan_parquet("./processed_merge_file_filtered.parquet")
print(filtered_sessions.head().collect(streaming=True))


sessions_features = extract_session_features(filtered_sessions)
sessions_features.sink_parquet("./sessions_features")
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at /home/runner/work/polars/polars/crates/polars-lazy/src/physical_plan/planner/lp.rs:153:28:
sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cpinon/Documentos/Project/SourceCode/project/data/01_raw/sessions/test_feature_engineering.py", line 50, in <module>
    sessions_features.sink_parquet("./sessions_features")
  File "/home/cpinon/Documentos/Project/SourceCode/project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1895, in sink_parquet
    return lf.sink_parquet(
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'
```

The error message suggests using collect().write_parquet(), but I’m not sure why I can't use sink_parquet() method. If I use the former solution, my computer runs out of memory, since it cannot process the entire dataframe.

Comment: Can you try using the `write_parquet` method with the [`row_group_size`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_parquet.html#:~:text=requires%20extra%20compute.-,row_group_size,row%20groups%20in%20number%20of%20rows.%20Defaults%20to%20512%5E2%20rows.,-data_page_size) parameter to control the size of the row groups written to the Parquet file? This may help you manage memory usage when writing large DataFrames to Parquet files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all polars operations are supported by the streaming engine. In particular, I would guess that this is what's keeping you from streaming:

```
(
    pl.col("Timestamp")
    .diff()
    .dt.seconds()
    .fill_null(0)
    .over("ID")
    .alias("time_since_last_session")
),
```

you can verify that by doing

```
print(sessions_features.explain(streaming=True))
```

you'll then get something that looks a little bit like:

```
print(pl.select(a=pl.lit(1)).lazy().select(pl.col('a').pow(2)).explain(streaming=True))
--- STREAMING
 SELECT [col("a").pow([2])] FROM
  DF ["a"]; PROJECT 1/1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"  --- END STREAMING

  DF []; PROJECT */0 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

You want to see everything in between the `--- STREAMING` and the `--- END STREAMING`. Any operations that are outside those lines aren't supported by streaming.

The official documentation on streaming is a bit lax but [here's](https://www.rhosignal.com/posts/streaming-chunk-sizes/) some extra info.

As far as getting what you need, you could do something loosely like in [Quasi sinking workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77106175/1818713) where you have to get a unique list of your `ID` and then loop through a filtered version.

Another idea would be to just use the [pyarrow dataset writer](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html) or duckdb as they may (I **don't** have specific knowledge on whether or not they do) be able to support your streaming need.